# How do I add values of a prompt together?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, prompt

I'm supposed to prompt the user to enter a string of numbers separated by spaces and alert the sum of those numbers.  I'm trying to get the values into an array and then add them up, but it's not working.  I've tried a ton of different ways.  Help please!

```
    var input = prompt("Enter a string of numbers separated by spaces");
    var numbers = new Array (input.split(" "));
    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
         sum += numbers[i];
    };

    alert(sum);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mUqfX/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, 2 issues with your code. First, `.split` returns an array so you don't need to wrap a `new` around it. Second, you need to parse the number otherwise your joining strings together. Try

```
var input = prompt("Enter a string of numbers separated by spaces");
var numbers = input.split(" ");
var sum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    sum += parseInt(numbers[i]);
};

alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems:

`input.split(" ")` returnss an array, so you don't need to place it in another array

Your `numbers` array contains strings, which you need to coerce to numbers to total them.

Try this:

```
var input = prompt("Enter a string of numbers separated by spaces");
var numbers = input.split(" ");
var sum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){

 sum += parseInt(numbers[i]);
};

alert(sum);
```